# Sitecore User Group May 2019 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are wicked excited to announce the May'19 meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group!

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

Sitecore Experience Accelerator Creative Exchange and Creative Exchange Live by Saad Ansari Sitecore Technology MVP 2019

Offline Tracking With The Sitecore Universal Tracker by Kamruz Jaman - Sitecore MVP @Konabos Consulting

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, May, 01, 2019 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, May, 01, 2019 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/260765704/) for more details and RSVP.